# ZeroMQ: what is a difference between zmq_recv() v/s zmq_msg_recv() calls?

Tags: zeromq

Is there a difference between `zmq_recv` and `zmq_msg_recv` besides the structure they return? Which one should be used with a `ZMQ_PAIR` socket?

---

This question is for ZeroMQ version 4.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The easier part: **`ZMQ_PAIR`** & all other archetypes can use both

The principle of separation helps all the present high level Scalable Formal Communication Patterns ( `{ PAIR | PULL | REQ | REP | XREP | XREQ | SUB | ... }` ) ignore details about services exposed for programmer to use "across them" and consider them as just a set of supported external use-cases.

This means one can use either: **a just plain `buf []`** equipped `aRetCODE = zmq_recv(...);` or a call to `aRetCODE = zmq_msg_recv(...)`, where **a bit more complex, pre-baked `zmq_msg_t`** object is expected to be well prepared & passed to the internal processing.

A failure to do all that well in the latter use-case can spit back an error flag ( **`aRetCODE == -1`** ) and set the details in **`errno == EFAULT`** -- which is an instance of error codes, explained as:

> **`EFAULT`**
>       The message passed to the function was invalid.

So both calls have the very same return value logic.

---

### The difference is in the call-signatures - the arguments passed

```
int zmq_recv (  void  *socket,           // yes, The Socket
                void  *buf,              //        a Buffer[] - byREF-> A STORAGE
                size_t len,              //        a Buffer length
                int    flags             // ZMQ details { ZMQ_NOBLOCK | ... }
                );
```

The simpler one is straightforward and almost self-explanatory.

The other one requires, as noted above a bit more care:

```
zmq_msg_t aMsgSTRUCT;                        // first: create aMsgSTRUCT
int       rc =  zmq_msg_init(  &aMsgSTRUCT );// next:  try intitialise it ( internality )
  assert (rc == 0);                          // test:  if things went well ( use this style, even when it has no error-code associated here, with zmq_msg_init() )
          rc =  zmq_msg_recv(  &aMsgSTRUCT, aSocket, ZMQ_NOBLOCK );
  assert (rc != -1);                         // test:  if things went well
...                                          // process: rc-bytes in aMsgSTRUCT
..                                           //
.                                            //
/* ALWAYS: */   zmq_msg_close( &aMsgSTRUCT );// finally: control dispose off
/* Release EACH message,
   these are
   not re-usable and
   require ZeroMQ internalities
   to take due care to release
   all their allocated resources
   */
```